# Adding vertical ticks at nodes on a horizontal like drawn with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, nodes, tikz-node

I have the following minimal code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[solid, thick]
(0,0) node [below]{0}
-- (2,0) node [below]{$n-k$}
-- (6,0) node [below]{$n$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This creates the image below:
[image]

How can I get short vertical tick marks at the nodes? By this I mean, how can I get the image to appear like the one below?
[image]

Note that the red colour is not necessary but it was just added to the image to make the desired result easier to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[solid,thick] (0,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[thick] (0,0.2) -- ++ (0,-0.4) node[below] {0};
\draw[thick] (2,0.2) -- ++ (0,-0.4) node[below] {$n-k$};
\draw[thick] (6,0.2) -- ++ (0,-0.4) node[below] {$n$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: picture]

Answer (score 4):

You can draw tick in the `\foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) -- (6,0);
\foreach \i/\j in {0/0, 2/n-k, 6/n}
\draw[draw=red] (\i,0.2) -- ++ (0,-0.4) node[below] {$\j$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]